# Designing layout, reuse views. Best practice

Tags: android

Im going to have several same fields in Activity

eg

```
Fragment A
Age
Height

Fragment B
Age
Weight

Fragment C
Weight
Height
```

Should I create layout for each fragment or is way to "dynamicaly" show fields I need

Comment: If it's just a small piece of the same or similar layout include it, if it is a bigger functional piece that appears on several screens maybe make it it's own Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [include tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). It's a very easy way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Also you can hide and show the views you need dynamically,  using the View.setVisibility() method, in the onActivityCreated() method of the Fragment class.